# How to fix Carousel component to a specific aspect ratio in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

carousel component seems can only set height. i want do like this but it not work.

```
<v-responsive :aspect-ratio="16/9">
    <v-carousel>
        <v-carousel-item v-for="item in [url1,url2]" :key="item" :src="item"> 
        </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
</v-responsive>
```